# Cognito - getInstance().getTokens() Error: Failed to federate the tokens

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-mobilehub

Works without an issue when calling

```java
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getClaim("sub");
```

Right after I login.

```java
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signIn(username, password....
```

However when I resume activity(go to another app) and come back and try getting tokens again I get the error:

```
D/AWSMobileClient: waitForSignIn: userState:SIGNED_IN
D/AWSMobileClient: Inspecting user state details
D/AWSMobileClient: hasFederatedToken: false provider: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_.....
D/AWSMobileClient: hasFederatedToken: false provider: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences
D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Clearing credentials from SharedPreferences

W/AWSMobileClient: Failed to federate the tokens
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1450)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
```

Not sure why. Heres my current awsconfiguration:

```
{
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "us-east-1:088e7bc3...",
                "Region": "us-east-1"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "us-east-1_....",
            "AppClientId": "50e3s5e....",
            "AppClientSecret": "1mbug...",
            "Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share if you have found solution for this issue.

Comment: @ArunBadole I gave up trying to find a solution. My issue is still up on their cognito github